# Discord.js | Is there a way to store variables into a different js file?

Tags: node.js

So I'm making a DS bot that will send a random link/images that I have provided the bot onto chat ever hour. I have a lot of links/images and it's a real big mess on the main index.js

Is there a way to take a variable from another js file to my main one?

Here is my code:

````
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello Foxi!'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The Dealer is listening at http://localhost:${port}`));

// ====================The Dealer's Heart====================

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

// 804488904634925076
//var bbChannel = client.channels.cache.get('809808576406093847');

//console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  setInterval(() => {
    var bbChannel = client.channels.cache.get('804488904634925076');
    const image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('HOURLY PICTURES')
      .setAuthor('Brought to you by: The Dealer')
      .setDescription('SOME IMAGES MAY REPEAT')
      .setImage(image)
    bbChannel.send(random)
  }, 3600000);
});


client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong!');
  } 
});

//Images
var images =["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "ETC"];

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);```
````

Comment: that depends on what exactly you want to do. You can always import a JSON file with all your links.

Comment: Oh I can? I'm not really familiar or experience in JSON files, I'm still relatively new to coding. Is there an example of some sort you can provide?

Comment: Sure, it's pretty simple actually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so, what you want to do is create another file in the same location as your current file. *Note: Only for simplification, you can of course create the file where you want but then you need to change the relative path to it*

We'll call that file `images.json` for now. In that file you use a simple JSON structure and basically put the array that you have at the bottom of your file in here.

```
{
    "images": [
        "link1",
        "link2",
        "link3"
    ]
}
```

Now all you have to do is import it into your main file. You do that as you would with anything else. We use [destructuring](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/es6-syntax.html#destructuring) here to only extract the value we want. *Note: You can also import the entire file if you have more then one entry that you want to access. After a certain amount, that is usually the way to go because it's not as much work. Programmers are a pretty lazy bunch*

```
const { images } = require('./images.json');
// if you want the entire thing you do this
// const images = require('./images.json');
// and then to access the array
// console.log(images.images);
```

If you use destructuring then you don't need to change your code at all because you already define the variable as you need it. If you don't then use the method described above.

Obviously you can now remove the array at the bottom of your code.

*Another Note: If you use a halfway decent IDE then it should give you autocomplete when you write your code and also let you know if something is wrong*